# Excel VBA save Word.Range in Header to Array

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently creating a macro that needs to save Word.Range instances to an array.
I want those range objects to be anywhere in the document. For the regular content stuff this works just fine, but when I am trying to save a range in the header, I cannot get it to work.

The sub definition:

```
Function GetSelectionRanges(rRng As Object, sFind As String) As Variant
```

`rRng` is a StoryRange

The code for the regular conntent ranges is as follows:

```
Set tmpSelections(i) = WdDoc.Range(Start:=rRng.Start, End:=rRng.End)
```

This one works absolutely fine and I can work with it.
I tried to extend it so it can store header objects as well:

```
Set tmpSelections(i) = WdDoc.StoryRanges(rRng.storytype).Range(Start:=rRng.Start, End:=rRng.End)
```

This, however, does not work. It says object does not support this attribute/method.

My problem at the moment is that the start and end are obtained correctly but if I use the `WdDoc.Range` method it uses the text stored in the regular content and thus not working as I want it to.

Definitions:

```
WdDoc As Object
tmpSelections() As Object
```

Later on I want to work with the single ranges and eventually replace values but that is a later step that cannot be incorporated in that routine.

Answer (score 1):

The [StoryRanges property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178940%28v=office.12%29.aspx) returns a collection of Range objects, so you don't need to call .Range.

If you want to select a range within the StoryRange, use SetRange:

```
Set tmpSelections(i) = wdDoc.StoryRanges(rRng.StoryType)
tmpSelections(i).SetRange Start:=rRng.Start, End:=rRng.End
```

Comment: The problem is I want only a certain number of characters not an entire range saved to the array.

Comment: The code above does the same as in your original example, ie it takes the whole range. If you'd like to take only part of the range, you can adjust the range eg using sr.SetRange 0, 100.

Comment: `Set tmpSelections(i) = WdDoc.StoryRanges(rRng.storytype).SetRange(Start:=rRng.Start, End:=rRng.End)` I get an error that an object is required, but I feel that the `SetRange` method is used incorrectly.

Comment: SetRange modifies the existing range rather than returning a new one, so you don't use it as an assignment ie set x = range.SetRange(start,end). You use it as a statement ie range.SetRange start,end